# Bootstrap carousel active class incorrectly applied when using tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Wordpress webpage with a Bootstrap Carousel which has no active classes set. These are all handled by JavaScript.

The webpage shows rooms available and each room uses its own tab. When the webpage first loads the first rooms carousel displays as it should and works correctly. The images slide as they should. If I then repeat the process of sliding through some carousel images for another room and then return back to the previous room more than 1 image is displayed initially.

This is because 2 items within the carousel have an active class and I don't know how to stop this from happening.

Here is the code which adds the active class to the carousel and tab.

```
$('div[class="carousel-inner"] div:first').addClass( "active" );
    $('ol[class="carousel-indicators"] li:first').addClass( "active" );


    $('#room-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function() 
    {
        var $tp = $('.tab-pane:visible');
        $tp.find('.item:first').addClass('active');


        scrollTo($tp, 40);

    });


  });
```

The staging website is http://thecurve.staging.wpengine.com/rooms/

I really struggle with javascript so a bit of help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you add the active class to the *first* item.
But when you return to an already slided carousel, there is an active item at second, third or fourth position. So after adding the class you have two active items, which then both are displayed.

A quick fix would be to remove all active classes before adding it again, like this:

```
$('#room-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', function() {

  $(".carousel-inner > .active").removeClass("active");

  var $tp = $('.tab-pane:visible');
  $tp.find('.item:first').addClass('active');

  scrollTo($tp, 40);
});
```